# How can I get the number of logins each day in the current month using awk?

Tags: awk, users, login, wtmp

I want to find out how many users logged in each day to my server in the current month. Starting from the first day of the month. Preferably I would like to use awk to do this.
My output should look something like this:

```
Apr 1: numOfLogins
Apr 2: numOfLogins
...
current day: numOfLogins
```

Comment: What operating system is your server running? Linux? BSD? Unix? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it like below :

```
last <user>  | awk -v dt="$(date +%b)" '$5==dt{ k[$5$6]+=1; a[$5$6]=$5"-"$6"-"$7  } END { for ( i in k ) { split(a[i],s,"-");print s[1]" "s[2]": "k[i]" No of Logins"  } }' | sort -n -k2
```

For non-specific to user:

```
last | grep -ve reboot -ve wtmp | awk -v dt="$(date +%b)" '$5==dt{ k[$5$6]+=1; a[$5$6]=$5"-"$6"-"$7  } END { for ( i in k ) { split(a[i],s,"-");print s[1]" "s[2]": "k[i]" No of Logins"  } }' | sort -n -k2
```

OR

List by users:

```
last | grep -ve reboot -ve wtmp | awk -v dt="$(date +%b)" '$5==dt{ k[$1$5$6]+=1; a[$1$5$6]=$1"-"$5"-"$6"-"$7  } END { for ( i in k ) { split(a[i],s,"-");print s[1]" "s[2]" "s[3]": "k[i]" No of Logins"  } }' | sort -n -k3
```

Comment: I don't want it to be specific for a user. Is it possible?

Comment: @Paralyz3d : Edited for non-specific user as u asked.... also i have added for group it by users.just in case if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If your `last` supports the `--since` option, you can limit to the current month with:

```
last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')"
```

The command `date +'%Y-%m-01'` prints the date of the first day of this month. For example, if I run it today, April 26th, 2020, I get:

```
$ date +'%Y-%m-01'
2020-04-01
```

So the `last` command becomes `last --since 2020-04-01`.

This means that all we need to do in awk is exclude the lines starting with `reboot`, the one starting with `wmtp`, and any empty ones and then count:

```
last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')" | awk '!/^reboot/&&!/^wtmp /&&/./{date=$5" "$6; a[date]++}END{for(date in a){printf "%s: %d\n",date,a[date]}}' | sort -nk2
```

Or, a little easier to read:

```
last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')" | 
    awk '!/^reboot/ && !/^wtmp / && /./{
        date=$5" "$6; 
        a[date]++
       }
       END{
        for(date in a){
            printf "%s: %d\n",date,a[date]
        }
       }' | sort -nk2
```

On my laptop, this returns:

```
$ last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')" | awk '!/^reboot/&&!/^wtmp / && /./{date=$5" "$6; a[date]++}END{for(date in a){printf "%s: %d\n",date,a[date]}}' | sort -nk2
Apr 3: 1
Apr 5: 1
Apr 20: 1
```

If this is something you will be using often, you can make it into a shell function by adding these lines to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent if you are not using bash):

```
monthLogins(){
    last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')" | 
        awk '!/^reboot/ && !/^wtmp / && /./{
            date=$5" "$6; 
            a[date]++
           }
           END{
            for(date in a){
                printf "%s: %d\n",date,a[date]
            }
           }' | sort -nk2
}
```

You can then run `monthLogins` and get your desired output.

Alternatively, instead of filtering out `reboot` and `wtmp`, you could filter for only existing user names with (assuming your shell supports the `<()` construct):

```
monthLogins(){
    last --since "$(date +'%Y-%m-01')" | 
     grep -f <(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd)
        awk '/./{
            date=$5" "$6; 
            a[date]++
           }
           END{
            for(date in a){
                printf "%s: %d\n",date,a[date]
            }
           }' | sort -nk2
}
```

Comment: In this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481188/109397) some words other than `reboot` are present in the `last` output (`runlevel`, `shutdown`). My plan was to get all usernames from `/etc/passwd`, then to exclude all lines, which are not them. By this way we protect yourselves from an unknown word occurrence.

Comment: @MiniMax fair enough. I added a version that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Many many thanks for Stalin Vignesh Kumar's answer. This code will display only the current month as determined by the system's month (**date +%b**), filter out the reboot user, which shows in the **last** command's output whenever a system is booted, and display **all** user's logins. I'll update my answer if I can figure out how to add leading zeroes to the output in the appropriate variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
last | grep `date +%b` | grep -v -e "reboot" | awk ' { k[$5$6]+=1; a[$5$6]=$5"-"$6"-"$7  } END { for ( i in k ) { split(a[i]"\n",s,"-");print s[1]" "s[2]": "k[i]" logins"  } }' | sort -n -k2
```